# random number post asp textbox

Tags: asp.net, random, textbox

i have a system that generates unique numbers for reference..here is my function in jquery:

```
        function random() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000);
        }

        function generateRandomNumber() {
            $("#GenerateCode").val(random());
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            generateRandomNumber();
        }
```

here is my mark up(asp):

```
       <div id="step3" class="formwiz">
       <h4>Step 3: Reference Number</h4>
            <br clear="all" />
            <p>  
             <label>Reference Number</label>
             <span class="field">
             <input type="text" id="GenerateCode" name="GenerateCode" class="smallinput" disabled="disabled" />&nbsp;<small style="color: red">Please write the numbers at the back of your check</small>
             </span>
             </p>
      </div>
```

this function works fine with html (input)...but when i shifted from input to ast textbox, the numbers are not posted in the textbox...do i need to use getelementbyid.?

please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a class instead so change the class attribute to:

```
class="smallinput random"
```

and change the javascript to:

```
$(".random").val(random());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a wild guess that you're actually using ASP.NET and not classic ASP and you try to change the text box to:

```
<asp:TextBox id="GenerateCode" runat="server" CssClass="smallinput" Enabled="False" />
```

In such case, the generated ID might be different than what you give it, if the textbox is part of control, placeholder or something like this.

To ensure same ID use `ClientIDMode` and set it to Static:

```
<asp:TextBox id="GenerateCode" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="smallinput" Enabled="False" />
```

Now the jQuery code should work fine again.